# Programmatically get to "Settings > Security & Privacy >Device Unlock" Page

Tags: java, android, google-pixel

I'm coding in java with Android Studio & deploying it to Google Pixel. Is there a way to programmatically get to "Device Unlock" page? (Settings -> Security and Privacy -> Device Unlock)

I have tried

`Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS); startActivity(intent);`

but unable find the code to get directly to "Device Unlock"

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etqOl.png)

[Security and Privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZJVE.png)

[Device Unlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS7Gx.jpg)